# Auto compile SCSS in netbeans plain java project

Tags: java, sass, netbeans-8

I am working on a small pet-project which is primarily a java desktop application. It has a embedded web server (tomcat) to allow for remote control.

I have made the design decision to go all out with modern HTML technologies, netbeans has been able to provide all the relevant IDE features required *EXCEPT* SCSS auto-compile ( this works perfectly well on a HTML project) but this is a "Java Application" style project (as I want to embed all the static html/css/js content inside my jar deployable and then drive my desktop application via REST.

Comment: Is it an option to use taskrunners (Grunt, GULP, ...) to detect file changes and start the compile? If yes I can give you an example

Comment: @crashbus , anything that can be integrated into a netbeans 'java application' project will suffice (I have no issues with this when running as a html application, but this paticlar project is 75% pure java, 25% html. ) . Something that can be integrated into the 'compile' step (not package would also be beneficial.).

Answer (score 3):

I guess you may be intressed in compiling your project with [libsass](https://github.com/sass/libsass). There are two implementations for [Java](https://github.com/sass/libsass/wiki/Implementations). In this case it is easily integrated in the `compilation` step.

If you are not satisfied with it, you can integrate a frontend task runner into your working environment. Consider [different options](http://blog.cozycloud.cc/technic/2014/06/18/task-runners-comparison/): Grunt, Gulp, etc.

I personally use Grunt for my daily routine. When speaking about Grunt, you will need to install two tasks: [`grunt-sass`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-sass) (it is different from `grunt-contrib-sass`) and `grunt-contrib-watch`. The second task compiles your `.scss` or `.sass` files on file-change. In this case you can have your `.jar` file filled only with desired `.css` files built for you by a task runner.